# Howto add Windows 7 in the grub on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: windows, grub2, menu

I searched all over the Internet but there are no solution to my problem, whatever I add, grub menu doesn't show up, I did a grub update but it doesn't detect windows, I don't know what to do, I have to log on Windows 7.

Comment: Just because you say Grub menu does not show up. Did you try to press and **hold** the **left** Shift key while booting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF you have ur windows 7 DVD, boot into recovery and open command prompt

type in

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

then

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

now reboot and insert ur ubuntu live cd and in terminal type

```
sudo update-grub
```

this should fix it

for more info on the bootrec tol visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Comment: I don't have one, but I think no one can't stop me with a USB, is there a special disk for recovery of W7?. Thank you anyways it is the solution at the end.

Comment: yeah usb works use a tool called unetbootin...

Comment: @SarveshLad - I have removed the link - whilst you put the warning, such links are not allowed on this site.  thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom I had my doubts ..... thanks ..
sorry for breaking the rule....

Answer (score 0):

Unetbootin isn't very user-friendly. I'd suggest Linux Live USB creator, which I think is linuxlive.org.